# Handling NaNs and missing values when producing libffm.txt file as input for Field Factorization Machine (xLearn)

Tags: nan, missing-data

I am setting up a field factorization machine (xLearn) and the inputs is a categorical variable that has NaNs. **My question is: what should the missing values be defined as when they are input into the ffm?** No matter what I set the values at (i.e. NaN or ''), I obtain the below .txt file. Is this file correct as the input for the ffm?

```
2 0:0:0.09772819999999999 1:2:1
4 0:0:0.26065900000000003 1:2:1
2 0:0:0.11356600000000001 1:3:1
1 0:0:0.062336199999999994 1:2:1
3 0:0:0.0 1:4:1
```

The "2" value is the NaN/missing value in the dataframe. This is the code I use to produce the .txt dataset (from the dataframe) and that I then input into the ffm: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/01/factorization-machines/

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore/skip the NaN entries that are numerical features.

Have a look at this snippet :

[Link to the code](https://github.com/wngaw/blog/blob/master/xlearn_example/src/utils.py#L29)

Sample Usage is available here : 
[Sample Usage of translating to FFM format](https://wngaw.github.io/field-aware-factorization-machines-with-xlearn/)